# problem with NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a core data NSManagedObject named CD_CoffeeShop . When i allocated a variable

```
CD_CoffeeShop *temp_CS = [ CD_CoffeeShop new]
```

and try to pass a value to it,

```
[temp_CS setCoffeeShopId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:coffeeShop.Id]];
```

(the variable coffeeShopId of temp_CS is a NSNumber)

i get an error that says :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CD_CoffeeShop
>   setCoffeeShopId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b34040'

What can it be ?

Comment: Have you declared `setCoffeeShopId` in the .h file?

Comment: they are declared dynamic, but also if i try to manually set it as temp_CS.coffeeShopId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:coffeeShop.Id]]; it won't work, it shows me the same error

Comment: is `coffeeShopId` synthesize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [Core Data Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)?  You do not instantiate core data objects with the NSObject methods.  You either obtain them with a fetch request if they exist already or you use [NSEntityDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSEntityDescription) to [insert a new object into the context](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-208209).

Definitely don't use `new`.

Comment: btw, can i add the objects after proper initialization to a NSMutableArray so that i may add them later to the DB?

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru: That's all handled for you.  If you create a new managed object in the proper way and assign some values to its attributes, when you later save the NSManagedObjectContext, all your changes will automatically be sent to the persistent store.